Bootstrap navbar looks weird when I place my image last
I want the button and the image to be side by side, and have the list of links below them when I click the button.
This is the before and after when I click the toggle button:
before clicking the toggle button
after clicking the toggle button
And this my code:
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top px-5">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="col-xxl-1 col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pt-3 mb-1 pe-2">
                <img src="/images/05.jpg" alt="cat" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid ">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                    <ul id="navbar-links" class="navbar-nav mb-lg-0 justify-content-around mt-4 w-100">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link fw-semibold fs-5" href="#">TEXT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link fw-semibold fs-5" href="#">TEXT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link fw-semibold fs-5" href="#">TEXT</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>```


I tried placing my code differently but it only works if I place my image first.


Ok, I hate sounding like one of those mods, but I suppose I have to:  What is weird to you may not be for others, or may not be evident for others.  You need to objectively describe what you don't like about what is being rendered.

@JoséRamírez fixed it
